# Android Studio Mass ImageView array

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making the English alphabet of imageview's in an app i am making and i was wondering what would be the best way of doing this?

Note: there is 26 letters in the alphabet!
What i need it to do:

> Make the imageview
>
> Set it's background
>
> Set the id
>
> Make it Clickable
>
> Add a click listener to every individual image view

Currently I have the following code (Yes i know it is very amateur)

```
public class Main_game extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_game);
        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLetters);
        ImageView[] letters = new ImageView[26];
        letters[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i1);
        letters[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do the task
            }
        });
        letters[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i2);
        letters[3] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i3);
        letters[4] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i4);
        letters[5] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i5);
        letters[6] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i6);
        letters[7] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i7);
        letters[8] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i8);
        letters[9] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i9);
        letters[10] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i10);
        letters[11] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i11);
        letters[12] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i12);
        letters[13] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i13);
        letters[14] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i14);
        letters[15] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i15);
        letters[16] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i16);
        letters[17] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i17);
        letters[18] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i18);
        letters[19] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i19);
        letters[20] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i20);
        letters[21] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i21);
        letters[22] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i22);
        letters[23] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i23);
        letters[24] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i24);
        letters[25] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i25);
        letters[26] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.i26);
    }
}
```

And my layout is setup like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLetters">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i1"
                android:background="@drawable/a1"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i2"
                android:background="@drawable/a2"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i3"
                android:background="@drawable/a3"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i4"
                android:background="@drawable/a4"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i5"
                android:background="@drawable/a5"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i6"
                android:background="@drawable/a6"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i7"
                android:background="@drawable/a7"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i8"
                android:background="@drawable/a8"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i9"
                android:background="@drawable/a9"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i10"
                android:background="@drawable/a10"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i11"
                android:background="@drawable/a11"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i12"
                android:background="@drawable/a12"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i13"
                android:background="@drawable/a13"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i14"
                android:background="@drawable/a14"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i15"
                android:background="@drawable/a15"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i16"
                android:background="@drawable/a16"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i17"
                android:background="@drawable/a17"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i18"
                android:background="@drawable/a18"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i19"
                android:background="@drawable/a19"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i20"
                android:background="@drawable/a20"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i21"
                android:background="@drawable/a21"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i22"
                android:background="@drawable/a22"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i23"
                android:background="@drawable/a23"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i24"
                android:background="@drawable/a24"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i25"
                android:background="@drawable/a25"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/i26"
                android:background="@drawable/a26"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/game_tabhost"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/gameTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:background="@drawable/hangman_0"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/helpTab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        layout="@layout/helptab_layout"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any easier way to do this?

I have tried making array's and such but none seem to work correctly. Sorry it's such a complicated problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much better solution: **Loops**!

Instead of copy pasting and slightly editing every line in your java code, you can also just create a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { //You might have to change that slightly depending on where you want to start/end counting
    int res = getResources().getIdentifier("i"+i, "id", getPackageName()); //This line is necessary to "convert" a string (e.g. "i1", "i2" etc.) to a resource ID
    letters[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(res);
    //setOnclicklistener for letters[i] and whatever you would like to do.
}
```

Also you should probably give them slightly better names than just "i[number]". :)

Comment: How did you get that so fast! I have tired may different loops that people have made and it's all just confused me.

Comment: I hope mine is not confusing you :) Just ask me if you would like me to clarify a step.

Comment: No the only thing that was confusing me was the `int res = getResources().getIdentifier("i"+i, "id", getPackageName());` because i didn't know how to do that step.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mark your answer as the correct answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
Use Listview/ gridview ...
Listen/gridview.setOnItemclicklistener
{
do your stuff..
}
```